# Local counter variable in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, local-variables

Is this acceptable by all C Standards?

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Or should I write it like this just to be sure it works everywhere?

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: No. You need to write second one.

Comment: There is only one C standard, which is currently ISO 9899:2011. And that accepts this very well. And the second version has different semantics.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's valid since C99 only. If you want your code to be valid under old standards use

```
int i;
for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
```

And also, [read this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931315/local-counter-variable-in-for-loop/34931335?noredirect=1#comment57595744_34931335) by @[JoachimPileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) it complements well this answer.

Comment: It might be worth noting that before C99 the variable need to be declared in the declaration block first in the function as well. One can't simply declare the loop count variable just before the loop (unless the loop is the first non-declaration statement in the function).

Comment: This has different semantics, as the scope of `i` is now that of the enclosing block, not just the `for` loop.

Comment: I sometimes `break` from a loop and use the value of `i` after the loop to see if it completed naturally. But if `i` has gone out of scope that is not possible.